# Data structure for modelling a containment/composite relation

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, go

I posted a similar message in golang mailing list, as it involve some language specific details. I hope the cuncurrency support native to the language may have a better way to model this than a pattern. If you are not familar with golang, please help me with your knowledge of data structure in general. I think most of my doubts are lanuage neutral and I had better response from SO.

I am trying model a storage area (has a containement relation like, storage -> Rack(s) -> Shelf(s) -> Bin(s).
As I learned, typically it may model with "composite pattern". But, in an effort to 
- Keep the structural (hierarchy) details seperate from objects
- Use the language constructs (channels to walk the tree etc)
I was thinking of modelling the information in a tree.I do not have an understanding of what is the best tree structure suitable for this application.

1. In go, I see two libraries implementing LLRB and treap. What would you recommend? Is there a more suitable data structure available?
2. Does the tree has to be balanced? for example, I may have only ine shelf in one rack, but can be arbitrariy long containment in others.
3. For quick traversal, I will keep it in memory. How do I manage loading, building and persisting the tree structure? Do I build the tree everytime I open the application, and do not persist the tree itself but the objects.

Comment: It's hard to say much about concurrency without knowing more about your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got good answers on the Go-Nuts list.  Sameer Ajmani's advice to start with  built in types is good.  Don't get bogged down in something more complex until simple solutions prove inadequate.  Si guy has your solution for persistence.  Gob is fast and simple.